# DateTimeOffset UtcDateTime vs ToUniversalTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am a bit lost as to why `DateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime` and `DateTimeOffset.DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` return two different times with the same kind (UTC).

Here is an example:

```
var dateTime = "2019-12-01T12:40:37-07:00";
var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateTime);
    
Console.WriteLine(dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime + " Kind: "+dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime.Kind);
Console.WriteLine(dateTimeOffset.DateTime.ToUniversalTime()+ " Kind: "+dateTimeOffset.DateTime.ToUniversalTime().Kind);
```

outputs:

```
12/1/2019 7:40:37 PM Kind: Utc
12/1/2019 12:40:37 PM Kind: Utc
```

You can find a runnable example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nj06yG

Aren't these methods supposed to return the same date/time value?

Comment: Per the docs, "the `DateTime` property is not affected by the value of the `Offset` property". Effectively the `Kind` you get from that `DateTime` is irrelevant because the time is neither local nor universal; the `.ToUniversalTime()` really doesn't do much of anything useful there. This property should not be used except as what it is; part of the component of the whole `DateTimeOffset`. This is also why `UtcDateTime` exists separately.

Comment: The two snippets are completely different. `DateTimeOffset.DateTime` returns the `DateTime` part of `DateTimeOffset` with all offset information lost, as Unspecified

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Wouldn't this be a design flaw then? I would've expected these two APIs to return the same information.

Comment: It's not a design flaw. What are you trying to do? What did you expect? The two calls are completely different

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you. The returned DateTime is actually in UTC which is quite confusing. I would have understood if the kind was unspecified but this isn't the case.

Comment: No it's not. You have no idea what it represented because you have no idea what the original offset was. The `DateTime` property returns the exact date and time part, without the offset. Without knowing that offset you have no idea if it was UTC or not. And you certainly can't say if it's local or not. It depends on your application requirements

Comment: It's a design flaw in the sense that `DateTime`'s `Kind` doesn't do much more than be confusing (*which* local time?), while `DateTimeOffset` has an explicit offset which removes all ambiguity. :P Hindsight is 20-20; there are many shortcomings of the way .NET treats date and time that have only been corrected (somewhat) with more recent innovations. The fact that both these properties exist and serve different purposes is not a flaw, though.

Comment: _"The returned DateTime is actually in UTC"_ - Only after you call `ToUniversalTime()`, mind you. Try without that call. I bet, you'll get "unspecified". => https://dotnetfiddle.net/fg4cq1

Comment: @Fildor Oh, that makes perfect sense then. I just removed `ToUniversalTIme()`, the kind is now `Unspecified`.

Comment: Had offsets been part of .NET from the start, `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` would probably not exist at all, or if it did, it would have been kind enough to throw an `InvalidOperationException` if called on an `Unspecified` value, since the operation would be ambiguous. Instead it just shrugs its shoulders and says "I'll just assume it's local time, I guess".